# Is there any YouTube API to share a particular video to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I would like to share a YouTube video to Facebook and Twitter from my python application. I have checked the api reference but I could find nothing.

Comment: You would need to look into Facebook and Twitter APIs/SDKs. Sharing a YouTube video is the same as sharing any other URL, or even text content.

Comment: @jdehesa so, I'm supposed to look up Facebook and Twitter api not YouTube?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @jdehesa I couldn't find any api for desktop application except web applications.

Comment: The APIs are HTTP, but that doesn't mean you cannot use them from desktop applications, you just need to send the adequate HTTP messages. There are plenty of libraries that give you an easy programmatic interface wrapping these APIs. Check out [here for Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html) or [here for Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks) (there are more 3rd-party libraries than what is listed in those lists, like this [Facebook SDK for Python](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/)).